# TOR Network: How to Prevent IP Change on each Website

Tags: tor

In Tor I am having trouble because each time I change the site address the IP changes as well. It there a way to have it use the same address for like a 10 minute interval?

Comment: Well, that sort of follows logically from the entire point of Tor -- routing each request differently.

Comment: It is causing errors on some page routing for some pages! There are a wide variety of configuration settings I am hoping there is something in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor already does this automatically... https://www.torproject.org/about/overview

You can tweak it by using the NewCircuitPeriod and MaxCircuitDirtiness parameters.

Alternatively, you can force it with StrictExitNodes and ExitNodes parameters... but be aware of the security implication of always leaving from the same exit!

Comment: By default it is changing my IP address each new site I visit. I have tried the NewCircuitPeriod 600 to wait 10 minutes, but I am not sure I am configuring properly. If I just add it to the \Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc file is that enough?

Comment: That should do it. You'll need the dirtiness tweak also though.